# Confused in using opensource 3rd party libraries

Tags: c++, c, build-process

How do you integrate C or C++ open-source third party libraries in your projects? Do you copy all the files it comes with (I.e. README, makefiles etc) to a separate directory somewhere inside the project and build it using its configs? Or do you only get needed source files and headers from a source package? Or do you just install pre-build binaries?

What's better if I'm making a very little non-GUI project for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Are you publishing as open source, or is this for in-house, or is this a commercially sold package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic way is to put in your `README` and `INSTALL` that you depend on a library and that the user should download and install the *shared* library. Then link against that shared library at compile time.

Never put the source into your own application unless theres a good reason (like gnulib).

Your application should have nothing to do with the installation of the third party package - leave that to the user. When they use `rpm`, `deb`, `ports`, or `portage` with the packages you build, which tell what it depends on, the other package will be automatically installed.